# Is setting an Oracle session variable from a web app a reliable way to pass a value from a web app to a trigger?

Tags: oracle, session, coldfusion, oracle10g, coldfusion-9

I have a lookup table in Oracle 10g with a trigger that populates a history table on insert, update and delete. I want to be able to capture the user ID from the ColdFusion app in the history table via the trigger.

One potential way I found to do this was by using Oracle session variables:
In the coldfusion code, I pass the user ID to the Oracle session right before the insert, update and delete code:

```
CALL dbms_session.set_identifier(12345);
```

In the trigger, I read the client_identifier var, swapping for "0" if null.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV','CLIENT_IDENTIFIER') INTO USER_ID FROM DUAL;
  IF USER_ID IS NULL THEN
    USER_ID         := 0;
  END IF;
```

In single user testing this works fine, but because I don't know how the CF app server's DB connections relate to Oracle sessions, I'm concerned that the value in the oracle session var will be unreliable with multiple simultaneous users.

Is setting an Oracle session variable from a web app a reliable way to pass a value from a web app to a trigger?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a cftransaction tag might increase the reliabilty.

Comment: There is no "CF Session" per se (unless you meant session variables which is a totally different concept). I do not know about Oracle, but typically each connection to the database is treated as a separate session. So if a pool has ten open connections, there are ten open sessions. Among other things, using cftransaction ensures the same connection is used for whatever sql is inside the transaction tag.

Comment: However, not all cfquery tags open new connections do they?  If a connection is open, wouldn't a new query simply use it?

Comment: What's the relationship between ColdFusion sessions and Oracle sessions? There is none. TBH, I think you need to articulate an actual problem, rather than a "concern". What's going wrong? Anything? Also TBH it seems like yer kinda rolling your own transactionality, which is... folly. Voting to close, pending you describing an actual problem.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Opening and closing of connections is handled by the connection pool. A request just says "hey I need a db connection" and is given one from the pool. The request does not know, or care, whether the connection is new or existing. Say you are running three queries.  The issue is whether you are guaranteed the *same* connection for all three operations. Most likely a request will keep the same connection for the life of the request. However, AFAIK, the only way to *guarantee* that, is to wrap all three queries in a cftransaction.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Yes, I found that phrase ambiguous as well, but chose to assume it was just an unfortunate choice of words. Brien - My response assumes you are referring to your dbms, and its concept of "sessions". Could you confirm that and add some clarification?

Comment: @leigh: I have a ColdFusion web app that talks to an oracle database. A user of the app operates within a ColdFusion session. That user follows a code path that sets an oracle session variable. What I want to know is how safe that oracle session var value is. Can it be clobbered by other app users? It appears that the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose rather than doing what you've outlined above (which I don't think is workable), you add a column to your lookup table (let's call it `MY_LOOKUP_TABLE`) in which you store the user ID of the user making the update (or insert) to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_lookup_table
  ADD update_user_id NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

(Assuming your lookup table isn't enormous and you don't mind setting a default for every existing row.)

The difficulty comes about when you need to delete a row from the lookup table ... how do you record the ID of the user who deleted it? In this case you would also need a column to record that the row was deleted, maybe `DELETE_FLAG`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_lookup_table
  ADD delete_flag CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL;
```

Then, in your update trigger, don't record updates where `DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER record_update
AFTER UPDATE OF my_lookup_table
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.delete_flag <> 'Y')
```

and when your app does a delete, you'll actually want an update followed by a delete:

```
<cftransaction>
<cfquery name="update_before_delete_lookup">
    UPDATE my_lookup_table
       SET update_user_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#user_id#" />
         , delete_flag = 'Y'
     WHERE <conditions>
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="delete_lookup">
    DELETE FROM my_lookup_table
     WHERE <conditions>
</cfquery>
</cftransaction>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that looks like the only way. I was really hoping to reliably pass a value to the trigger so I wouldn't have to double-step like that.